# Why cant i do these 2 jquery functions

Tags: jquery

I like to try this in jQuery but it won't work.. The two click functions work seperate but not together.. Why is this and how do i fix this?

```
$("p").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("test"); 
});

$(".test").click(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("test");
})
```

Can some one shine some light on this?

Comment: What do you mean by `not together`?

Comment: this is my pen, http://codepen.io/shiva112/pen/addoNY

Comment: Nothing is wrong with those event declarations as long as they are happening before the DOM is initialized.  Also the newer jQuery method is to use `.on` function

Comment: oke can you show in a demo?

Comment: You want `jquery toggleClass` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJJOKM

Comment: If you're just wanting to toggle the class, use `.toggleClass()`. Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrrOaL

Comment: Thank you! toggleClass it is... so sorry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Example of Current Implementation](http://Http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeebqp)

**HTML**

```
<p>Dit is een jq test</p>

<div class="test">Dit is een jq test</div>
```

This will allow both your events to fire because the class exists on the element on event binding.

---

### [Example to Accomplish the intend Goal](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJJOKM)

**JS**

```
$("p").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("test"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because

```
$(".test").click();
```

This part of script runs when page loaded first time and bind click event of those element which has test class (Initially there is no such element and we are adding test class dynamically on click of 'p').

```
function(){$(this).removeClass("test");}
```

this part of script run every time on click event of elements which has test class on page load (Initially no such element was present so this code wont be called ever).

This code will help you understand execution flow:

```
 $("p").on('click',function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("test"))
                $(".test").removeClass("test");
            else
                $(this).addClass("test");
        });
```

Best approach to solve your problem:

```
$("p").on('click',function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("test");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this at the end of the page just before the closing 'body' tag:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("p").on('click',function(){
         $(this).addClass("test"); 
       });

       $(".test").on('click',function(){
          $(this).removeClass("test");
       })
    })
</script>
```

NOTE: I have slightly changed your code making use of the 'on' event.

Comment: This doesn't work, as the element `<p>` doesn't have a class of `test` and no other element has a class of `test` when the dom is ready. `toggleClass()` works for this case..